# Elasticsearch filter exists and function_score

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to apply a [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query, along with a filter that returns only those results where a certain field is not null (the [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query), in Elasticsearch 5.4.1.

The scoring functions work as expected, but I'm unsure how to apply the `exists` query in context of `function_score`.

Example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "name_of_field"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dis_max": {
                    "queries": [{
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "term",
                            "fields": ["name^3", "other_names"]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "known_as": "term"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                "filter": {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "known_as": "term"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 200
            }, {
                "filter": {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "term",
                        "fields": ["name^3", "other_names"],
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 10
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this? can you please share here if yes